# Pig is not running :Unhandled internal error. jline.Terminal.getTerminal()Ljline/Terminal;

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

When I try to run the pig via terminal and give the command pig.

It shows error:

```
16/01/22 02:51:54 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : LOCAL
16/01/22 02:51:54 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : MAPREDUCE
16/01/22 02:51:54 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Picked MAPREDUCE as the ExecType
2016-01-22 02:51:54,470 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.13.0 (r1606446) compiled Jun 29 2014, 02:27:58
2016-01-22 02:51:54,470 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /home/vij/pig_1453459914465.log
2016-01-22 02:51:54,514 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /home/vij/.pigbootup not found
2016-01-22 02:51:54,551 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. jline.Terminal.getTerminal()Ljline/Terminal;
Details at logfile: /home/vij/pig_1453459914465.log     

in bashrc :`#PIG Setup
export PIG_HOME=/home/vij/pig/pig-0.13.0
export PATH=$PATH:/home/vij/pig/pig-0.13.0/bin
export PIG_CLASSPATH=HADOOP_INSTALL/etc/hadoop`
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed jline jar from `hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib`.

Now pig are working.

Answer (score 1):

I got it running successfully by adding:

```
    export CDH_MR2_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
    export HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true
```